# how to make sure a string updates to correct value if 2 transactions read and write at almost the same time POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

An entry in a table has a column whose type is a string that I am using to store the primary key id of some rows in another table, along with some other data. For example, it looks like "1:yes_2:no_3:no_". I have a method that reads the value of the string and replaces part of the read string with something else before writing the new result into the database. ex;

```
def replace(person):
    cur.exeucte(select stringcol from tablename)
    fetchedstring = cur.fetchone()
    # some code that might take 10 seconds to run, or 20 seconds to run. requires knowing information            #fetchedstring so I cannot put it above the fetch.
    if person == 'jack':
        newstring = fetchedstring.replace(1, "blue")
    if person == 'joe':
        newstring = fetchedstring.replace(2, "green")
    cur.execute(update tablename set stringcol = newstring)
    conn.commit()
```

So jack wants to turn "1" in that string into "blue" and joe wants to turn "2" in that string into "green". in most situations (and the behvaior that I want), this being called one after the other would result in the string "blue:yes_green:no_3:no_". However I am wrorried about what happens if it is called at almost the same time. This would be allowed because at first they are just reading the value of the string. for jack the string reads "1:yes_2:no_3:no_" and in the method changes the string to "blue:yes_2:no_3:no_" before writing "blue:yes_2:no_3:no_" to the database. For joe, when the string was read it was also "1:yes_2:no_3:no_", and changes the string in the method to "1:yes_green:no_3:no_" before writing that value into the database, losing the changes that joe had made. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? I am sure there are many but I am not sure which one would be the best bet / most standard way to do this. Please let me know if I can make the question any more clear, and thank you for the help.

I Read about transaction isolation but am still confused and concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The design is problematic because it requires holding transactions open for an extended period of time. This results in significant scaling problems. Design issues not withstanding, the following addresses the stated concern:

```
SELECT stringcol FROM tablename FOR UPDATE
```

Without a `WHERE` clause to restrict the affected rows, this will lock every row in the table and prevent updates for the duration of the transaction.

Please refer to [The Locking Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) in the PostgreSQL documention for additional information and cautions.

Comment: So I had tested this on my local database, and when I ran "SELECT col FROM table WHERE id = % FOR UPDATE, and then had the code sleep for 10 seconds before it ran the update, I found that I was still able to read from the row I had selected for update as this one was still ongoing.